# Bing WPF Map Control Pushpin Color

Tags: wpf, bing-maps

I'm trying to create a pushpin with a solid color on a Bing Maps WPF Control:

```
pushPin.Background = new System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush(MyMapColors.Green);
```

Despite using a SolidColorBrush, the pin that gets drawn has a gradient or a reflection of some sort.  How do I make this solid?

[image]

Alternatively, if I could reproduce the look of the pushpin, that would work as well.  I need to place a corresponding graphic on my search results list and I want the images to match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pushpin has a gradient in the pin template above the circle for the background color. The only way around this is to create a custom pushpin image and use that instead of the default pushpin. Like this: [image]

Comment: OK, that makes some sense.  Would I be correct in assuming that pushpin template is the entire pushpin with a transparent circle in the center where the color and text is displayed?

Comment: The default template has the gradient. You can create a custom user control that consists of an image that has the pushpin with a hole for where you want the color, and then place an ellipse behind the image and bind a color to it. This will allow you to change the color from code. Here is an example I made using HTML5: http://www.bing.com/blogs/site_blogs/b/maps/archive/2013/04/10/html5-canvas-pushpins-in-javascript.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Just for information: the link given by rbrundritt is broken, but is available on the Wayback Machine at:

https://web.archive.org/web/20140909183241/http://blogs.bing.com/maps/2013/04/10/html5-canvas-pushpins-in-javascript/